# distance to pixel conversion for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I'm trying to find distance to pixel conversion for Xamarin.iOS. I know this is how you do it natively, but how would you do this in Xamarin / c#??

MKCoordinateRegion myRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.centerCoordinate, 400, 0);

CGRect myRect = [mapView convertRegion: myRegion toRectToView: nil];
NSLog(@"width for 400m is %f", myRect.size.width);

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ObjC:

```
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.centerCoordinate, 400, 0);
CGRect myRect = [mapView convertRegion: myRegion toRectToView: nil];
NSLog(@"width for 400m is %f", myRect.size.width);
```

#### `Xamarin.iOS` Conversion:

```
var myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance(mapView.CenterCoordinate, 400, 0);
var myRect = mapView.ConvertRegion(myRegion, null);
Console.WriteLine($"width for 400m is ${myRect.Size.Width}");
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This is perfect! I upvoted, but it doesn't count it because of my low rep.